# how to change paragraph by clicking header in a loop manner details below tell you everything?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new in javascript so please brothers help me i will be appreciated :)
how can text change of paragraph everytime i click a heading like first time paragraph is empty when i click header paragraph becomes "1M" second time i click it becomes "1F" when 3rd time i click it becomes again empty and than process continues with every click like when i click again paragraph becomes "1M" and so on .

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have your title fire a javascript event that will update the div inner html. like so:

```
<script> 
  var pos = 0;
  var inputs = ["F1", "1M", ""];
  function changeContent() {
    var div = document.getElementById('content');
    div.innerHTML = inputs[pos];
    pos++;
    if (pos == 3) pos = 0;
  }
</script>


<h1 id="title" onclick="changeContent()">Title</h1>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for help but when i put the function on <h1> and id on a <td> of my table it didnt work but when i checked on "edit fiddle" it worked can you you please explain me and help me it will be appreciated :)

Comment: The onclick event fires the changeContent function. In this function we select the element with id 'content' and populate it using the innerHTML attribute.

Comment: brother my project is travel website where a male or female comes for ticket booking i create a mini bus internal scene where i make some seats by using css html and every seat is a different <h1> when a person come it click the <h1> or seat 1 than a table shows that 1M if person click 2 times than table shows 1F and in third time table becomes empty and so on person click 2nd seat on first click table shows value 2M and 2nd click shows 2F and process goes on for every seat please help me out about this brother i m in so tension and i m new in this field please help me out :( please :(

Comment: I don't see exactly what you mean. Are you trying to do multiple of these?
 maybe post your code on https://plnkr.co

Comment: please description will tell you every thing here is also a code

Comment: Ok try have a look at this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/gDF9NFSf0DboWwnfBUsb?p=preview
What I did is set seats object which holds the gender (0=F,1=M,2="") for each seat number.
Furthermore, no need to duplicate the function, you can add as many seats as you need, just increment the seat number you send to the function.
Hope it helps.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/gDF9NFSf0DboWwnfBUsb?p=preview 

you are genius to me you helped me alot now one and last thing i want from you you will definitely react angry but i need help for my university project which is almost done except this 

description will tell you everything

Comment: you just sent the same link so I updated it, but the idea is for u to understand. Not just copy the work!
https://plnkr.co/edit/gDF9NFSf0DboWwnfBUsb?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/lgxEyvuJj3w6rjKO4RVf?p=preview
last time mistakenly sent the previous comment again sorry but i wanted to send to this sorry to bother you again description will tell you everything and i got it the gender part thanks in advance :)

Comment: last thing i want if u help me

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/HRgCv7jq5DXWFVixvemB?p=preview 
check this buddy :( little change

Comment: thanku v v v much <3  
 have facebook account or skype and wanna friend let me know my 
facebook account k.mushab@yahoo.com

Comment: brother please need a little help here u will understand the situation after reading the description i gave please

https://plnkr.co/edit/4u1FTzw7DcnDaDaVXjxw?p=preview